# Problems with Arrays on Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this problem:
I have a search in the component "Table" (PrimeNg).
This search is to start when I post a character in the input. The search is correct, but when I clean the entry, the values do not return. This line at the beginning is just for this "this.groupExamples = this.Examples group;" but apparently when I change the elements of an array the other is affected.

```
  public getGrupoExames(){
    this.serviceExames.getGrupoExames()
      .subscribe((response)=> {
        this.grupoExames = response;
        this.grupoExamesAux = response;
      }, (erro)=> {
        console.log("Erro");
      });
  }

private filtarGrupoExames(event){
    let filtro: GrupoExame[] = [];
    this.grupoExames = this.grupoExamesAux.slice();
    for(let i = 0; i < this.grupoExames.length; i++) {
      let grupo = this.grupoExames[i];
      let listaExames = [];
      for(let j = 0; j < grupo.exames.length; j++){
        let exame = grupo.exames[j];
        if(exame.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
          listaExames.push(exame);
        }
      }
      grupo.exames = listaExames;
      filtro.push(grupo);
    }
    this.grupoExames = filtro;
  }
```

Comment: Bruno, I think you're on the right track. You'll need to fire those observers when the form value changes. That'll allow you to reset the values. Consider adding a timeout between keystrokes and only make the request once the user stops typing.

Comment: Post your controller and template so people can help you further

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you display whatever is inside your grupoExames, if that is correct you can try this structure

```
if(event.target.value.length > 1) {
  do the filter
 }
 else {
     this.getGrupoExames();
   }
```

Maybe another more ambiguous solution is to create a button to delete the filter and access to all the content .

Hope it helps you!